# Can I get the circulating supply of a token on Ethereum directly from the chain?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, erc20

I want to get a circulating supply to calculate the marketcap of erc20 token.
Usually we can check it on etherscan.io.

For example: https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#tokenInfo

But I do not want to get it from a third party API; I hope to get it from on the chain directly.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can all `totalSupply()` function on [the token ERC-20 smart contract](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/) using its ABI.

Comment: totalSupply and circulatingSupply is different, as circulatingSupply excepts all locked tokens.

Comment: There is no API to get circulating token supply. There is no standard for lockups. It is all based on Excel spreadsheet submitted to different services.

Comment: No, there is api which returns circulating token supply.
Check Etherscan api carefully, and you will notice that it exists.

Comment: Etherscan seems to only return totalsupply as well. Did anyone figured this out? https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens